# how to distribute more ones using random function in python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I would like to make a list that contains value of '1's than other random number.

let's say I want 60% of '1's appear out of 10 elements.
so 6 elements of 1s and 4 elements with random.
here is how I approached.

```
import numpy as np
import random

# to avoid generating 1s..
list_60 = np.random.randint(2,11, 10) 

array([ 6,  2,  8,  6,  6,  3,  5, 10,  6,  8])


count = 0
percentage = int(len(list_60)*(0.6) + 0.5)
for i in range(0,len(list_60)):
    if count < percentage:
        list_60[i]=0
    count += 1

list_60
array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  5, 10,  6,  8])


random.shuffle(list_60)
array([ 1,  1,  1,  6,  1,  5,  1,  1,  8, 10])
```

Precedure STEPS:

1. create randint from 2 to 10.
2. loop each element and based on the percentage. and change the element to 1s.
3. shuffle the list for more variation.

I don't think this is smart way of generating more 1s. Is there fancy/smart way to create weighted randomness?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to be an exact amount of 1s in the result; or do you want to choose each value independently, with a bias? Also, *why are you using Numpy* for this?

Comment: Yes it has to be exact amount of 1s. 60% of 10 elements in the list. So 6 elements of 1s should be there in the list. I used numpy library to generate randoms.

Comment: thanks just edited!

Comment: Initialize the list to have exactly six 1's, then add four more random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a random subset of indices, and then set those indices with 1:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(2, 11, 10)
index = np.random.choice(len(arr), int(len(arr) * 0.6), replace=False)
arr[index] = 1

print(arr)
```

You can also do this without numpy:

```py
import random

arr = [random.randint(2, 11) for _ in range(10)]
index = random.sample(range(len(arr)), int(len(arr) * 0.6))
for i in index:
    arr[i] = 1

print(arr)
```

The above two implementations use 10 + 6 random bits. You technically only need 4 + 4 (4 for the random numbers, and 4 for their random positions (thanks to @KellyBundy for noticing this). You can achieve this in numpy with:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones(10)
index = np.random.choice(len(arr), int(len(arr) * 0.4), replace=False)
arr[index] = np.random.randint(2, 11, len(index))

print(arr)
```

Or even simpler using plain python:

```py
import random

arr = [1] * 10
for i in random.sample(range(len(arr)), int(len(arr) * 0.4)):
    arr[i] = random.randint(2, 11)

print(arr)
```

Comment: How about minimizing the use of random data? Like, instead of 10+6, only 4+4 random numbers.

Comment: The shuffle one looks like 4+10 to me, though I guess the 10 might use decreasing numbers of random bits. What I meant is [this](https://tio.run/##LYvBCsIwEETv@xVzTKRIt3oQwS8pPQSsdcEky5qLXx@30LkMw7ynv/au5XJT612yVmuwVJ41EyUzPDDzghN4pFc1CKQc//mbsn7W4GtbA49xwDXeCR4XZ1ncPci9pLQwDWCORGr7cir2/gc), and I'm curious about the best numpy way to do that (I'm a numpy noob).

Comment: you're right, still 10+4, lemme give it another crack

Comment: edited my response to fix the error